# OpenCV heatmap for type 32FC1

Tags: android, opencv

I am trying to plot the R channel of an image as a heatmap using the following code:

```
// Read image as a Mat of 32bit float
Mat imgMain = new Mat(n_height, n_width, CvType.CV_32FC4);
image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("img.jpg");
Utils.bitmapToMat(image, imgMain);
imgMain.convertTo(imgMain, CvType.CV_32FC4);
// Extract R channel
Mat imgChR = new Mat(n_height, n_width, CvType.CV_32FC1);
extractChannel(imgMain, imgChR, 0);
// imgChR processed with floating point arithmetic
// Convert to HeatMap
normalize(imgChR, imgChR, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX);
Mat heatOut = new Mat(n_height, n_width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
applyColorMap(imgChR, heatOut, COLORMAP_JET);

// Save as Image
pimage = Bitmap.createBitmap(n_width, n_height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(heatOut, pimage);
File f = new File("heat.jpeg");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
pimage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
fos.close();
```

For averaging multiple copies of the image, I am converting the matrix from integers to floats. (The averaging process is abstracted in the following code but please note that the type has to be converted to a 32bit float)
Using the following code, I simply get a black image.

Is this the right approach for plotting a heatmap of a single channel matrix?
If not, is there any other function or approach that can be used?
(When I check the type of heatOut the function returns a 0 as a integer representation of the Mat type.)

Comment: applyColorMap expects uchar [0..255] input (not float [0..1]) . also you don't have to preallocate heatOut(it will get overwritten anyway and the output will be CV_8UC3)

Comment: @berak. Thank you for the comments. If heatOut gets an CV_8UC3 output, can I use imwrite() to save heatOut as an image file?

Comment: sure you can do that. (seems easier, too ;)  just use `Mat heatOut = new Mat()`

Comment: With the modification, I do get the write image, but I am not sure if the colorScales are working. I tried JET and AUTUMN but both return a greyscale image. Do I have something missing?